# Jar not finding resources

Tags: java, jar

I'm working on a project and compiling and running through my IDE works fine. All resources are found and it works properly. However, when I build my .jar it's able to find some resources but not all. My project structure looks like so:

```
src
    res
        image.png
        image1.png
        about.html
    tmp
        somefilehere.txt
    myFile.java
```

When I run my jar file it's able to find the images and use them, however when I try to access the html file it won't open. Here's what the project structure for the jar;

[image]

I haven't messed around with jar files before so this may seem very obvious mistake I am making. Any help is appreciated thanks!

EDIT: Code that accesses the file which isn't being found,

```
private void openURL(String url) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
    }
    ...catch exceptions...
 }
```

EDIT: Structure of the jar file looks like,

```
META-INF
res
    image.png
    image1.png
    about.html
tmp
    somefile.txt
myclass.class
```

Comment: The answer to this depends on how you're building your jar.  Can you provide details?  Some people do it with maven, some people do it by hand, others with ant, or scripts.  You can put pretty much anything in a JAR.  However you're building it isn't including these resources, but we can't tell you why if you don't post how you're doing it.

Comment: We also need to see your code and any error messages. Are you trying to use `File`?

Comment: I'm actually not sure... I'm using IntelliJ 13, and I just went into artfifacts, added a jar file into it then build it through there.

Comment: @chrylis there are no error messages, I'll update the OP with the code that accesses the file.

Comment: What is the value of url? Is it referencing the file system directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that you've all resources in project folder. While building jar, you need to  attach working directory. Make sure that directory contain resources. I tried out it in netbeans & jar is working fine showing images. What I usually do... I select src folder as working project folder & that folder contain res folder for images. Try it. I hope it would help.

Comment: Just tried it didn't work, will edit the OP with the structure of how the jar file looks.